# Clustering a list of similar categorical words and phrases in python

Tags: clustering, k-means, pattern-recognition, k-nearest-neighbour

I am trying to cluster a list of words/phrases in the context of similarity (not semantic).

I have a large dataset of categorical variables. In a perfect world, the categorical variables would have a limited number of unique types (**WASH DISHES, CLEAN HOUSE, REMOVE GARBAGE**) and this would be easy to do.

Unfortunately, there is a lot of noise as people have entered the data in a sloppy way. For example the entries could be variations of those words such as (**DO DISHES, WASH DISHES, CLEANUP, CLEAN HOUSE, THROW AWAY GARBAGE, etc**). The noise can also include spelling mistakes and symbols/numbers.

My current approach is to see the by value count breakdown of words and phrases, and essentially see what the most common ones are throughout the dataset. I then use this knowledge to manually determine the rough categories and compare the individual entries to the general categories using a string comparator metric and cluster in this way. This works relatively well.

My question is whether there is a more elegant solution where I do not have to manually analyze the most common words/phrases and be able to cluster autonomously.

I have considered using KNN, but would it be possible to apply it in this case? If so, then how would I go about it?

Comment: This seems to be pre-analytic question. You should first free the text from garbage and insignificant words, correct mistakes, lemmatize or stemmatize. For English language, many good programs exist for such tasks.

Comment: Can you give an example of such programs? I am working in python if it helps to know.

Answer (score 1):

No clustering can do this just on this data.

You absolutely need language knowledge.

Even by advanced string similarity measures "wash dishes" and "thrash dishes" or "wash fishes" are very similar. You need *a lot of additional data* to infer that they are quite different, whereas "clean up the kitchen" that has little characters in common is more similar.

Don't expect clustering to <strike>magically solve your hard problems</strike> *be able to wash your dishes*. Clustering algorithms "only" optimize some *statistical* property such as minimizing (x-y)². It's you job to map your problem into a vector space, where this optimization solves your problems.